# Ratios: Algebra Problem Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The present ages of Ram and Shyam are in the ratio $5:6$. Five years ago, the ratio was $4:5$. Find their present ages.

I tried,
Let the age of Ram be $x$
Let the age of Shyam be $y$
 
Accordingly, Ram's present age $=5x$
             Shyam's present age $=6y$
            Five years ago:
            Ram's age $=x-5$
            Shyam's age $=y-5$
Accordingly, Ram's age $=4(x-5)$
             Shyam's age $=5(y-5)$

I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call Shyam's present age $x$, and Ran's present age $y$, we now have that:

$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{5}{6}$$

Five years ago would mean that their ages would be $x-5$ and $y-5$. we then can conclude that:

$$\frac{x-5}{y-5} = \frac{4}{5}$$

Solving for x:

$$6x = 5y$$

$$x = \frac{5y}{6}$$

Substituting:

$$5x-25 = 4y-20$$

$$5*\frac{5y}{6} - 25 = 4y - 20$$

$$25y - 150 = 24y - 120$$

$$y =30$$

And therefore

$$x = \frac{5}{6}*30 = 25$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac rs=\frac56\text{},\\ \frac{r-5}{s-5}=\frac45.$$

Turn to an ordinary stytem of linear equations
$$6r-5s=0,\\5r-4s=5.$$
and solve by [Cramer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems).

$$r=\left| \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -5 \\ 5 & -4 \end{array} \right|/\left| \begin{array}{cc} 6 & -5 \\ 5 & -4 \end{array} \right|=25,\\s=\left| \begin{array}{cc} 6 & 0 \\ 5 & 5 \end{array} \right|/\left| \begin{array}{cc} 6 & -5 \\ 5 & -4 \end{array} \right|=30.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that the solution is integer. Then
$$r=5k,\\s=6k,$$ by the first proportion.

And $$\frac{5k-5}{6k-5}=\frac45$$ by the second.

The numerator is a multiple of $4$ for $k=5$, which happens to give the solution,
$$r=25,\\s=30.$$
(Rewriting $25k-25=24k-20$ also quickly leads to the solution.)

Answer (score 1):

If the current ages are x and y respectively, then 5 years ago the ages would have been $x-5$ and $y-5$. So,

From statement 1, $$\large \frac{x}{y}=\frac{5}{6}$$

and  From statement 2, $$\large\frac{x-5}{y-5}=\frac{4}{5}$$

rearranging, $5x-25=4y-20$

$\implies \large \frac{25y}{6}-4y=5$

$\implies y=30$

Then, $x=25$ years.